# How to mark person as registered on submit Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture, cloudpagesurl

I have a cloudpage form with smart capture and 3 fields.  I also have an email that redirects to the page `<a href="%%=redirectto(cloudpagesurl(3126))=%%">Link to web</a>`

The thing is when I send myself a test email and click submit, nothing happens?  THe cloud pages is linked to a data extension but the submit button does nothing when I click submit - any ideas?

Basically the goal is to mark a person as registered when they click the button

[image]

Comment: if you open dev tools on your browser is there any errors when you click submit?

Comment: It seems like subscriberkey was missing the _ so this is solved thanks!